# Device Statistics in Tracking's Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Is it possible in Email Studio's **Tracking > Sends** tab to get the device/platform info e.g. a pie chart on the devices on which the email was opened or clicked?

Otherwise is this possible through Automation Studio's **SQL Query activity**?

Answer (score 2):

Device stats are not available via any standard data view. You can, however, do a data extract activity in automation studio which can be configured to include this using the check box "user agent"

Comment: Thank you! Could you specify where this option is located?

Comment: Hello, when you configure a data extract you will be able to select it. In some cases it may not be there, but can be requested via ticket to support :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three avenues to get the information you're after:

**1) Return Path Integration**

- Third party paid service
- See the "[Email Client Monitor](https://returnpath.com/solutions/email-deliverability-optimization/email-client-monitor/)" section within the Return Path Dashboard
- Summary [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZh9raD983M)

**2) Discover Reports in Analytics Builder**

- Requires 'Discover' feature to be purchased and enabled on your account.
- Relevant Report: "Email Performance by Device"

[image]

**3) Tracking Extract in Automation Studio**

- Request SF Support to configure the extract type: "Tracking Extract"
- Request SF Support to enable "Include User Agent Information"
- see [Extract Outputs Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_extract_types_reference.htm&type=5)

[image]